# Fresh Install of 14.04.1 LTS No Display

Tags: nvidia, system-installation

I am very, very new to Linux in general. Always wondered, finally decided to give it a go. I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (most current on the site), which installed with no hiccups. Overwrote my Windows 7, since this is an extra computer just taking up space. After install it boots to a black screen with a flashing cursor/underscore. No response no matter what I do.

Installed on an old hp a1430n with a nVidia GeForce 6150LE graphics chip in it. Did some research and many people said there are initial issues with nVidia. Cool, I can read and follow instructions.
Said to try to use the install CD to "Try Ubuntu" and write some lines in a terminal. Try that, Linux comes up and then freezes when I touch anything. Has happened every time I tried, which is at least 8.
Said to open up a GRUB menu and do some things in there. Said to press/hold shift when booting. Tried every way they mentioned, no success. No GRUB menu.
Tried a reinstall, or 3, with different options chosen. No luck there. Messed with BIOS options. Did nothing.
 So I have a PC with an operating system on it. No way to get to a menu to install or uninstall drivers or programs. Should I try a different version of Ubuntu, or a different Linux variant? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try: antiX

antiX is a fast, lightweight and easy to install linux live CD distribution based on Debian Testing for Intel-AMD x86 compatible systems.

antiX offers users the "antiX Magic" in an environment suitable for old computers. So don't throw away that old computer yet!

It should run on most computers, ranging from 64MB old PII 266 systems with pre-configured 128MB swap to the latest powerful boxes. 128MB RAM is recommended minimum for antiX. The installer needs minimum 2.2GB hard disk size.

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/antix-linux/MX-14.3-non-pae.iso

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution for you, but the first time you read it, it may look more like superstition because it seems that what I discovered about three years ago is as yet completely undocumented online.

When your screen goes dark, press Ctrl-Alt-F1, THEN press Ctrl-Alt-F7

What you are doing is taking Ubuntu first into Terminal Mode and then out, and for some reason on this one computer I had, doing so would un-stick the graphics.  I don't understand why it worked, but for over a year it was the only way I could use my old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, as seen in [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233163&p=13121089#post13121089)
But here's what I did to solve it; short form:

-Check the CD with Checksum and Check Disk on the installer menu, accessed by pressing SPACE when you get to the screen with the person and the keyboard on the bottom (Accessibility Screen).

Also, as suggested by forum user grahmmechanical:
after accessing the screen with the purple guy, instead of checking the disk from there, scroll and find Try-Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu. When you get here, do not hit enter, but instead press F6. You will be greeted with a boot options menu, select `nomodeset` and hit return. Hit Install and you should be good to go.

Good Luck!